# Add class in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I use NetBeans 6.7.1 and I'm more used to C and php than Java.

I have a .class file containing "public class myclass". And in that class I have a private array and a public function getArr returning that array.

In the main class I have this

```
Object mcl = new myclass();
```

myclass is found by NetBeans and the above is accepted. But

```
String[] arr = mcl.getArr();
```

throws "Cannot find symbol" for getArr.

The file containing that class is in the project and the class found in code completion. But not the function, or I should probably call it a method.

I don't know if this is Java or NetBeans specific. But how do I get the main class to understand what it can find in my new class? And the compiler?

Am I missing some declaration?

Comment: Try changing it to `myclass mc1 = new myclass();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining mcl as an `Object`, which doesn't have a `getArr()` method -- `myclass` does.  You need to do:

```
myclass mcl = new myclass();
```

Then you will be able to refer to all the methods of `myclass`.

The reason that you're able to define it as an `Object` is because all classes in Java automatically extend `Object`, so it is their superclass.  But when you define an object as `Object` instead of their actual class, you only get to use the methods provided by superclass `Object`.